# organize node app with express and access modules from routes files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I generated a basic app using npm express. I was given the following app.js file, and now I'm trying to add more modules but I can't seem to access them in the route files. For example I added the module request and when I try to make a request from index.js I get the error `500 ReferenceError: request is not defined` how do I make it so that I am able to access new modules what I add from other routes?

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**/routes/index.js**

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        //console.log(body);
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            res.send('worked');
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the object to your route using. Here is how I'd do it.

**routes/index.js**

```
var module = null;
exports.setModule = function(mod){
  module = mod;
}
exports.index = function(req, res){
  //You can now use your module here
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

**app.js** 
(sending the fs module)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var routes = require('./routes');
routes.setModule(fs)
```

Although why not simply requrie the module you need on each file? If the module is singleton, I don't see any problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to require request inside your module in order to use it:

```
var request = require('request');

exports.index = function(req, res){
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        //console.log(body);
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            res.send('worked');
        }
    });
};
```

Alternatively, you could make the module's export a function that returns the route object (passing in request explicitly):

```
module.exports = function(request) {

  return {
    index: function(req, res){
      request(options, function (error, response, body) {
          //console.log(body);
          if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            res.send('worked');
          }
      });
     }
   };
};
```

with `var routes = require('./routes')(request);` in `app.js`. That lets you centralize dependency declaration, but can feel a bit tangled-up in terms of declaring a dependency in one place only to use it in another.